# I have made a BlackJack game myself but a part of the program does not execute

Tags: java, input, blackjack

What the problem is that in between User2's input is not accepted?

```
 public static void main() throws IOException
 {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      int user1total = 0, user2total=0, i;
      char userchoice;

      System.out.println("Welcome to the game of BlackJack!!!");
      System.out.println("User1 will be drawing two cards at a time");
      System.out.println("User2 will also be drawing two cards at a time");
      System.out.println("User1 shall win if User1's total reaches 21 or the User2's total exceeds 21");
      System.out.println("User2 shall win if User1's total reaches 21 or the User1's total exceeds 21");

      for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
      {
          System.out.println("User1's Total ="+user1total);
          System.out.println("User2's Total ="+user2total);

          if(user1total>21)
          {
              System.out.println("User2 wins as User1's total has exceeded 21");
              System.exit(0);
          }

          if(user2total>21)
          {
              System.out.println("User1 wins as User2's total has exceeded 21");
              System.exit(0);
          }

          if(user1total==21)
          {
              System.out.println("User2 wins as his total is 21");
              System.exit(0);
          }

          if(user2total==21)
          {
              System.out.println("User1 wins as his total is 21");
              System.exit(0);
          }
          System.out.println("Want to take two more cards, User1???");
          System.out.println("Enter Y or N");
          userchoice = Character.toUpperCase( (char)in.read() );
          if (userchoice=='Y')
          user1total=user1total+randomnumbersforuser();

          System.out.println("User1's Total ="+user1total);
          System.out.println("User2's Total ="+user2total);

          System.out.println("Want to take two more cards, User2???");
          System.out.println("Enter Y or N");
          userchoice = Character.toUpperCase( (char)in.read() ); ***//This part does not take input at all***
          if (userchoice=='Y')
          user2total=user2total+randomnumbersforuser();

          System.out.println("User1's Total ="+user1total);
          System.out.println("User2's Total ="+user2total);
          }
      if(user1total>user2total)
      System.out.println("User1 wins as his final total is greater than User2's total");
      if(user2total>user1total)
      System.out.println("User2 wins as his final total is greater than User1's total"); 
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you learn to debug.

Comment: Don't let anyone tell you that you can't do something because you're 14! Seriously, though, if people use a term you're unfamiliar with, [Google it!](https://google.com/).

Comment: Yeah, [debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging).

Comment: @GoldRoger: that answer has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Yuki No thats exactly the problem..`\n` enter key is left behind from first `read` which is taken in by second `read` instead of user input..anyways i gave link to scanner..removing it

Comment: @GoldRoger: oh, you're right! I was expecting it to not be doing line buffering for some reason. (wah, why did you delete your comment?!)

Comment: I really appreciate Yuki Izumi for saying so. I will not lose hope. Thanks man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `String[] args` as argument to main. `public static void main(String[] args)`
2. Remove `throws` from main. You cannot make `main` throw something. There is nowhere to throw.
3. Initialize all the variables that you use. e.g. you did not initialize `userchoice`. Insert the line `char userchoice = 0;` at the beginning.

Your code should work now.

Comment: 1.String[] args is only needed when one needs a method call window, which I do not require.
2.throws is a keyword which is used to link IOException with the main, so I require that.
3.And userchoice needs not be instatiated to zero as the value dirctly changes to the user input. And even if I was going to instatiate it i would instantiate to " " not to 0.